# Calculate Derivative, given data file

Tags: c, loops, scanf, derivative

So, this is a C programming problem I was given for class. To do this problem, you need to know the basic form of a derivative. Here are the instructions.[image: lab7problem2]

**Here is what I was trying to do...**
Given the txt file, I would read in a value, then read in the value ahead of the just read value. I tried to use two `for` loops, but that doesn't seem to work as expected. I can't use arrays in this program--(this would make this problem trivial, in my opinion).

*There are currently four `for` loops. The first pair are used for calculating f'(x) and the second pair is used for calculating f''(x).*

Here is my code. It's a lot of commenting, sorry in advance.

```
// Lab7_Prob2.cpp : Computes derivatives of functions... FML
// nxt3

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#define SUCCESS printf("File operations were successful!\n");

/*function that calculates derivative*/
double derive(double x_i, double fX_i, double x_i2, double fX_i2) {

/*x_i, f(x_i); x_i2 = (x_i + 1), fX_i2 = f(x_i + 1)*/
double fprime = (fX_i2 - fX_i) / (x_i2 - x_i); //derivative of x, f'(x)

return fprime; //returns f'(x)
}

int main() {

double x, fX, x2, fX2; //init variable for x and f(x); also, (x_i+1) and (f(x_i+1))
double fP, f2P, xp2, fXp2; //init variables for f'(x), f''(x), f'(x_i) and f'(x_i+1)
int i = 1, j = 1; //indices for both MAIN loops, i = MainLoop1, j = MainLoop2
int ss = -99; //sentinal signal for secondderiv.txt
FILE *dt; //ptr for deriv_testdata.txt
FILE *fd; //ptr for firstderiv.txt
FILE *sd; //ptr for secondderiv.txt

dt = fopen("C:/Users/ng00947/Downloads/DataFiles/deriv_testdata.txt", "r"); //opens deriv_testdata.txt
fd = fopen("C:/Users/ng00947/Downloads/DataFiles/firstderiv.txt", "w"); //creats firstderiv.txt
sd = fopen("C:/Users/ng00947/Downloads/DataFiles/secondderiv.txt", "w"); //creats secondderiv.txt

int mNumDataPts; //number of records from deriv_testdata.txt
fscanf(dt, "%i", &mNumDataPts); //grabs number of records from file
fprintf(fd, "%i\n", (mNumDataPts - 1)); //prints number of records to firstderiv.txt

//209 data points for f'(x)
//208 data points for f''(x)

/*loop scans in a uses derive function to calculate f'(x)*/
for (i; i <= (mNumDataPts - 1); i++) { //MainLoop1
    fscanf(dt, "%lf %lf", &x, &fX); //grabs values in each row for x and f(x)

    /*loop grabs values one ahead of x and f(x); this is for (x_i+1) and f(x_i+1)*/
    for (int k = i; k <= (i + 1); k++) { //SubLoop1
        fscanf(dt, "%lf %lf", &x2, &fX2);
        break; //leaves this loop to continue with main loop
    }

    fP = derive(x, fX, x2, fX2); //calculates derivative using function
    fprintf(fd, "%.2f \t %.2f\n", x, fP); //prints x and f'(x) to firstderiv.txt
}


/*loop scans in and uses derive function to calculate f''(x)*/
for (j; j <= (mNumDataPts - 2); j++) { //MainLoop2
    fscanf(fd, "%lf %lf", &x, &fP); //grabs values in each row for x and f'(x)

    /*loop grabs values one ahead of x and f'(x); this is for (x_i+1) and f'(x_i+1)*/
    for (int m = j; m <= (j + 1); m++) { //SubLoop2
        fscanf(dt, "%lf %lf", &xp2, &fXp2);
        break; //leaves this loop to continue with main loop
    }

    f2P = derive(x, fP, xp2, fXp2); //calculates second derivative using function
    fprintf(sd, "%.2f \t %.2f\n", x, f2P); //prints x and f''(x) to secondderiv.txt
}

fprintf(sd, "%i \t %i", ss, ss); //prints sentinal signal to end of secondderiv.txt

/*closes all files*/
fclose(dt);
fclose(fd);
fclose(sd);

SUCCESS; //prints message for sweet victory

return 0; //let's wrap this up
}
```

I appreciate any and all help! (Bonus points if you can help answer my question without providing code.)

Here are the datafiles:

[File given, deriv_testdata.txt](http://pastebin.com/8i1ErK08)

[First Derivative, firstderiv.txt](http://pastebin.com/XngiVM7t)

[Second derivative, secondderiv.txt](http://pastebin.com/VPnU0vGQ)

Comment: This may not solve the issue, but highly recommend to check the return value from `fscanf()` which should be `2` is most (if not all) cases in the code.  The check may seem superfluous but robust code uses it and it is a good practice to adopt, even here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest simplifying the `scan()` loops.

Scan the first pair.  In a loop (starting at index 1) scan the next pair, calculate the derivative and print.  Use the 2nd pair as the next set's first pair.

```
static const char *format2double = "%lf%lf";  // space not needed in "%lf %lf"
if (fscanf(dt, format2double, &x, &fX) != 2) Handle_Error();

for (i = 1; i < mNumDataPts; i++) {
  if (fscanf(dt, format2double, &x2, &fX2) != 2) Handle_Error();
  fP = derive(x, fX, x2, fX2);
  fprintf(fd, "%.2f \t %.2f\n", x, fP); //prints x and f'(x) to firstderiv.txt
  x = x2;
  fX = fX2;
}
```

Comment: What type is `y` and `y2`? No where in this loop are `y` and `y2` used.

Comment: @Nate Thanks for the query - meant `fx` and `fx2`.

Answer (score 0):

To Calculate First Differentiation f'(x). I think You Should Change your Sub loop to

`for (int k =  i+1 ; k <= (i + 1); k++) //change k=i+1`

That would be same solution to find Double differentiation f''(x). change your sub loop to

`for (int m = j+1; m <= (j + 1); m++); //change m=j+1`

****But in this loop You wrote `continue;`
just before the end of `for()`loop, I think that's illogical, because any how that loop will continue to begin its next iteration even if you remove it. I think You might want to write `break;` at that line( as you wrote in earlier sub loop when finding f'(x) )***

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything. However, for some reason, the way my program is set up now (including what you wrote), it skips values of X.

Here is the data file. I'm reading in the x values (first column) and the f(x) values (second column); the values of x never change, so when I'm printing them to the new file, the first column should be the same in all three files. This isn't the case.

File given: [deriv_testdata.txt](http://pastebin.com/8i1ErK08)
First derivative: [firstderiv.txt](http://pastebin.com/XngiVM7t)
Second derivative: [secondderiv.txt](http://pastebin.com/VPnU0vGQ)

Comment: After calculating f'(x) you created a file firstderiv.txt, To calculate f''(x) you are reading this same file which is opened in "write mode",you cannot read a file which is opened in write mode,so you have to change this to `fopen(" firstderiv.txt","r+");// change r to r+`. Before calculating f''(x) you also have to make sure that they are again being read form starting point in the file, by adding these `rewind(fd);` and `rewind(dt);`